# How to get user's geolocation

Tags: geo-location

`Using Sitecore 10.1`

`Xdb.Enabled` & `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` values are set to true and the layout file has - `@Html.Sitecore.VisitorIdentification()`.

The following values are null.

```
var country = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Interaction.GeoData.Country;
var city = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Interaction.GeoData.City;
var latitude = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Interaction.GeoData.Latitude;
var longitude = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Interaction.GeoData.Longitude;
```

I'm assuming, Geolocation services are a part of this version. right?
If yes, is there any config setting to change, to fetch the above values?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to subscribe to the GeoLocation service if you haven't yet. You can do this through the self-service portal which you can find at https://support.sitecore.net. See [here for more details](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/101/sitecore-experience-manager/en/set-up-sitecore-ip-geolocation.html#UUID-313cf105-8d87-db18-b314-d07089d71bdc_id__Subscribe_to_the) on signing up for the service.

If you've subscribed you also need to activate the IP Geolocation service through configurations. You can do this be setting the value `GeoIp.PerformLookup` to `true` in `webroot\App_Config\Sitecore\DetectionServices.Location\Sitecore.CES.GeoIp.config`.

More information [can be found here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/101/sitecore-experience-manager/en/set-up-sitecore-ip-geolocation.html).

Comment: Is it possible to check anywhere in the system (CMS) if the current license has this subscription already?

Comment: I don't believe there's anywhere in the CMS itself you can see it, I think you'd have to go through the support portal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sitecore Geolocation API to achieve this functionality. Hope you raise a request to Sitecore to activate the Sitecore IP Geolocation service. If not you can refer to Sitecore documentation for the same: [Set up Sitecore IP Geolocation](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/101/sitecore-experience-manager/set-up-sitecore-ip-geolocation.html)

1. Get the `Visitor IpAddress` like below:

```
if (Tracker.Current?.Interaction?.Ip != null)
 {
    string ipAddress = new IPAddress(Tracker.Current.Interaction.Ip).ToString();
 }
```

2. Now from the IpAddress you can fetch the rest of the details like Region, Country, Post Code, Longitude and Latitude, etc. You can find the code below:

```
var geoIpManager = Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService();
var geoIpFetchedData = geoIpManager.GetGeoIpData(ipAddress);
if (geoIpFetchedData.Status == GeoIpFetchDataStatus.Fetched && geoIpFetchedData.WhoIsInformation != null)
  {
    var  country = geoIpFetchedData.WhoIsInformation.Country;
    // other details
  }
```

It internally uses `GeoIpManager Service`.

You can use `Sitecore.CES.GeoIp.Core.Lookups.LookupManager.GetWhoIsInformationByIp(...)`, as well but `GetWhoIsInformationByIp` will be removed in a later version of Sitecore but it will be present for backward compatibility.

```
var geolocation = Sitecore.CES.GeoIp.Core.Lookups.LookupManager.GetWhoIsInformationByIp(ipAddress);
if (geolocation != null)
  {
    var city = geolocation.City;
    var postCode = geolocation.PostalCode;
    // other details
  }
```

See the blog post for more reference: [Sitecore Geolocation Service API](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2021/09/sitecore-geolocation-api.html)